# Text Editor(Sublime Text, Geany, Notepad++ etc.) Regex to remove all parameters from URL string except one parameter-value

Tags: regex, url, text-editor, google-search, url-parameters

I am not very familiar with advanced matching patterns in Regex.

I have some Google Search URLs which I need to clean up without having to hold Backspace key for 5 seconds to remove unnecessary parameters from the URL.

Let's say I have this URL(could many different URLs following patterns like below):

```
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=Ne4pXpSIHIW_9QOD-rmADw&q=laravel+crud+generator&oq=laravel+crud+generator&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l8.1294.6845..7289...1.0..0.307.3888.0j20j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....6..0i131j0i362i308i154i357.PwlZ_932pXo&ved=0ahUKEwjU9pz4tJrnAhWFX30KHQN9DvAQ4dUDCAU&uact=5
```

And I want to turn that into nice clean Search URL as below:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+crud+generator
```

How can I acheive that using Find/Replace with Regex of any of mentioned text editors in Question ?

Comment: Do all your urls start with `https://www.google.com/search?` have `q=...`? Is there _always_ `&...` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, pretty much all the time, that's why I want to keep only one parameter `q` and it's value, so need only the one `?` and no need for `&` then. But I think the problem might be with pattern matching the various weird text values, the other parameters could have, as you have already seen in the culprit url in the question.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/7QTPWF/1 check it

Comment: That works like charm, thanks @HamedGhasempour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting that others use the solution.

[image: Replace]

in notepad++ please press `CTRL+H` then select Regular expression on below.

Then place on `Find what:` this pattern: `.+&(q=[^&]+).+`
and in Replace with insert: `https://www.google.com/search?$1`

Now, easily press the `Replace` button for single replace or for all replacements press `ALT+A` or `Replace All` button.

Check [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7QTPWF/2)

But description:

1- `.+&` find all characters before `&` following a `q`. So this part includes `https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=Ne4pXpSIHIW_9QOD-rmADw&`

2- `(q=[^&]+)`, our target! we want everything after `q=` up next `&`. So we search for a string which started with q= then any character which is not `&`. `[^&]` means a character that is not `&` and `+` is saying that any character that is not `&` more than zero time. this part will include `q=laravel+crud+generator`. **Please notice the parentheses**.

3- `.+` means any character and includes `&oq=laravel+crud+generator&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l8.1294.6845..7289...1.0..0.307.3888.0j20j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....6..0i131j0i362i308i154i357.PwlZ_932pXo&ved=0ahUKEwjU9pz4tJrnAhWFX30KHQN9DvAQ4dUDCAU&uact=5`

ok, remember `()` in section 2? that was a group. you can use groups in replacements by this pattern `$groupNumber` which groupNumber is the index of parentheses. Here we have just one `()` or actually just one group, so our replacement statement will be `$1`.

**And finally replacement**: `https://www.google.com/search?$1` so everything is inside group one will replace with $1.

Comment: I think you missed the parenthesis in the pattern in this line "Then place on Find what: this pattern: .+&(q=[^&]+).+ and in Replace with insert: https://www.google.com/search?$2", I see the parenthesis are there in the Notepad++ screenshot and in Regex101 code.

Comment: I changed the pattern bro. Post Updated ;-) I described what I did. Feel free to ask anything :-)

Comment: That's great man, really descriptive and informative answer. Marking it as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this pattern: `(https://www.google.com/search\?).*(q=[^&]+).*` with `$1$2`

Explanation:

- `(https://www.google.com/search\?)` = matches the beginning of your specified string. Notice the escaped `?` since it's a special character. Wrapped in parenthesis, this becomes capture group #1 (accessible by `$1`)
- `.*` = this will match any characters and is also optional. Just to clear out anything between the start of the string and your `q` parameter
- `(q=[^&]+)` = matches your `q` parameter up until the `&` symbol (indicating next parameter). Wrapped in parenthesis, this becomes capture group #2 (accessible by `$2`)
- `.*` = this will match any characters and is also optional. This part clears out anything after your `q` parameter's value

Replacement:

- `$1$2` = Simply replaces your string with capture group 1 and capture group 2

** Tested in Notepad++ with sample string in question

Comment: It doesn't work reliably when the search term is long with spaces. Try with long search terms like `laravel 5.5 crud tutorial example step by step from scratch`. With the default Google search url, if you run this pattern, then it truncates some parameters from the end giving `https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+5.5+crud+tutorial+`. I got this after testing in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0):

Find: `(?<=search\?).*?(laravel\+crud\+generator).*`
Replace with: `$1`